# ASP.NET MVC Rewrite Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, maproute

View following route:

```
 context.MapRoute(
        name: "General",
        url: "general/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "general", action = "list", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "Catalogi.Web.Controllers.General" }
 );
```

Here you can have the following url routes:

```
/general/suppliers
```

Which will take you to the list action.

But the following also works:

```
/genera/suppliers/list
```

Is is possible to redirect the second url to the first one? And this for multiple controller names?

Because else you have duplicated urls and I would like to eliminate this.

Comment: Is this the only route or are there other routes defined (elsewhere)?

Comment: Both urls are calling same controller and action. Why do you want to redirect? I get the impression that you want to do url rewriting instead of redirection?

Comment: its the only route for this area, but we have mutilple areas ( general is one area ). Yes I mean rewriting, I only want to have the first one active, the second one needs to be rewriten as /general/suppliers

Comment: You can create default index() ActionResult that will handle `/general/suppliers` you can redirect it to /general/suppliers/list through your code.